# datagridview bind to a list of doubles

Tags: vb.net

I have an excel table with two columns (Date, objectives). I need to pull the objectives numbers based on todays week and bind it to the first row in datagridview. I'm able to pull the numbers with the code below but binding it doesn't work. all it does is add a new empty column. any idea why ? appreciated.

```
 Private Sub bindit()
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = String.Format(ConnectionNoHeader, FileName)}
        cn.Open()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(
            <Text>
                SELECT 
                 date,
                    objectives
                    FROM [<%= Sheetname %>$] 

            </Text>.Value, cn)
        dt1.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        dt1.AcceptChanges()

    End Using

    Currentweek = MyCalendar.GetWeekOfYear(
       Now,
       CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek,
       DayOfWeek.Sunday
   )

    For Each row As DataRow In dt1.Rows
        If IsDBNull(row.Item("objectives")) Then
            row.SetField(Of Double)("objectives", 0)

            Value = MyCalendar.GetWeekOfYear(row.Field(Of DateTime)("date"),
                                                 CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            Value1 = MyCalendar.GetYear(row.Field(Of DateTime)("date"))
            Console.WriteLine("Date: {0} Week: {1} Year: {2} Objectives: {3}",
                              row.Field(Of DateTime)("date"),
                              Value, Value1,
                              row.Field(Of Double)("objectives")
            )
        End If
    Next
    Currentyear = MyCalendar.GetYear(Now)


    ThisWeekTotal = (
            From Row In dt1.AsEnumerable
            Where MyCalendar.GetWeekOfYear(Row.Field(Of DateTime)("date"),
                                           CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek,
                                           DayOfWeek.Sunday) = Currentweek And MyCalendar.GetYear(Row.Field(Of DateTime)("date")) = Currentyear
            Select Row.Field(Of Double)("objectives")
        )


    bsData.DataSource = ThisWeekTotal.ToList()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bsData

End Sub
```

Comment: Does ThisWeekTotal contain any items? Debug and inspect it or temporarily remove the "Where" clause.

Comment: yes items are there. I just don't know how to bind them dgv